# scripted resize kvm images

Tags: kvm-virtualization, lvm, iscsi, proxmox

I'm examining the possibility to script the resizing of a kvm image. The goal is to give our customers the possibility to upgrade their vps online. So for instance if a customer has a vps of 10G then they get the option to upgrade to 20G and set the time when the server restarts for the upgrade to take effect. 
The resizing of the image it self won't be much trouble, but how to script the resizing of the partition and file system inside the vps?
I was wondering if it's possible to do this in a robust way and if someone has done this before. I couldn't find much about this on the internet.

At the moment I'm using proxmox2 with ubuntu 12.4 LTS guests.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

May be this link can help u ..
http://humblec.com/is-it-possible-to-do-online-resizing-of-guest-block-devices-or-without-shutdown/

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! We really do prefer that answers contain content not pointers to content. Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.